# EF Code First Relationship issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm working with Entity Framework Code First at the moment but I'm facing some troubles getting the relationship to work properly..

I have the following:

```
public class StockLevel : BaseEntity
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public int StockLevel { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

My Product table and entity is already working, but when I start building the StockLevel table, I want it to include a Product object, so in StockLevel table, there'll be a ProductId foreign key that references a product on the Product table, but I don't want to modify the Product entity in EF, but I'm getting the following error:

> The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

Answer (score 0):

As the error states you need to configure the relationship using fluent API or Data Annotations. I'm more familiar with Data Annotations, so I'll use them in my answer.

To indicate that the Product property is set using ProductId you need to add a ForeignKey attribute to your ProductId property:

```
[ForeignKey("Product")]
public int ProductId { get; set; }
```

and that should be enough to make it work. See the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/gg193958.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement get and set methods as follows:

```
public string ProductName
{
    get
    {
        if (this.yourEntityReference.EntityKey == null) return "";
        else return (string)this.yourEntityReference
            .EntityKey.EntityKeyValues[0].Value;
    }
    set
    {
        this.yourEntityReference.EntityKey
           = new EntityKey("YourDB.YourTable", "ColumnName", value);
    }
}
```